# Resultset that shows if one row is in a table or not

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I have two tables A and B.
Their relationship is A has_many B.

Rows in A can be in B, or not.

So, how can I retrieve all rows in A, and have a field in the resultset that says for each row if it's in B or not?

For example, A has these ids: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

And B has these A_ids: 1, 2, 3

So the result set would be:

```
1 true
2 true
3 true
4 false
5 false
```

I use PostgreSQL, but maybe it's irrelevant.

Comment: Read up on outer joins. I show a solution using a left outer join. That is bring all rows from one table even if none are found on other table this lets you check if the optional table returns a value or returns null which in turn answers this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM   B
                      WHERE  B.A_id = A.id) THEN 'True'
         ELSE 'False'
       END AS InB
FROM   A
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Any reason you go for this over an outer join?

Comment: @JustBob - In SQL Server it gets optimised into a semi join. No idea if the same is true in PostgreSQL.

Comment: You actually don't need the case in Postgres as it has a true boolean data type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Good point, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/37f7e/1)

Comment: So what does that make the SQL statement look like?

Comment: @MartinSmith could you update your answer to optimize it for PostgreSQL please? Attaching that SQL Fiddle would also be nice :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, if you put your Fiddle into an answer I will accept it, as all are using case, and as you state it's not necessary in Postgres.

Comment: I just tried explain (analyze, verbose) and found that in fact PostgreSQL optimizes this one quite well and actually prepares, in my test case at least, as alternatives a nested loop index scan and a sequential hash join.  It never executed the loop and just did the hash.  Quite impressive. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct
  a.id,
  case when b.a_id is null then 'false' else 'true'
from
  a left join b on b.a_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a left outer join.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE a (a_id INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE b (b_id INTEGER, a_id INTEGER);


  INSERT INTO a(a_id)
  VALUES (1), (2), (3);

  INSERT INTO b(b_id,a_id)
  VALUES (1,3);

  select a.a_id,
         CASE WHEN b.a_id IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END    
  from a
  left join b
         on b.a_id = a.a_id;





  result:
  1|FALSE
  2|FALSE
  3|TRUE
```